# React-select: i need to retain user typed input onblur when user has not yet selected an option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

My react select gets cleared if the user has not selected an option and clicks outside the component or changes tab.

i want to retain user typed input so that they can continue typing from where they left off

What i have seen as solution from others is to set state on input change as follows:

```
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleInputChange = (inputVal, action) => {
        if (action.action !== "input-blur" && action.action !== "menu-close") {
            setInputValue(inputVal);
        }
    }

    <AsyncSelect
                ref={(ref) => {
                    selectRef = ref;
                }}
                placeholder={'Search Merchant'}
                inputValue={inputValue}
                defaultOptions
                loadOptions={loadOptions}
                openMenuOnClick={false}
                onChange={getSelectedValue}
                onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                isClearable
                noOptionsMessage={() => 'No merchant found!'}
    />
```

This does help to keep the user typed input and continue typing from there but now each time a character is typed, the state is updated and in my load options function it is doing multiple api calls

```
const loadOptions = (searchValue) =>
        new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            if (searchValue.length > 2) {
                debounce(() =>
                        searchMerchant(searchValue).then(
                            response => {
                                ...
                            }
                        )
                ,1000)()
            }
        });
```

How can i solve this issue of multiple api calls